# Code runs with out error but it is not saving the file

Tags: excel, vba

It is supposed to open the file, save as, copy values, Save as again (final filename), then to delete the first save as. I am using this to achieve a temporary .xlsx file. It works, opens, saves as window comes up, then deletes the Temp file but it is not saving the file before it deletes the temp file.

Code:

```
 Sub PracticeMakesPerfect()

Dim wbMain     As Workbook
Dim Alpha      As Workbook
Dim Beta       As Workbook
Dim sFile      As String
Dim PurgeTemp

Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    Set wbMain = Workbooks("Macro Tester.xlsm")
    Set Alpha = Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\frfcomputer\Desktop\Test.xlsx")
        ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs "C:\Users\frfcomputer\Desktop\test\Temp.xlsx"
    Set Beta = Workbooks("Temp.xlsx")

wbMain.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").Value = Beta.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").Value

Application.DisplayAlerts = True

        Application.GetSaveAsFilename

ActiveWorkbook.Close

'Source File Location
sFile = "C:\Users\frfcomputer\Desktop\test\" & "Temp.xlsx"  

'Sets Object
Set PurgeTemp = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

'Checks File Exists or Not
If PurgeTemp.FileExists(sFile) Then

    'If file exists, delete the file
    PurgeTemp.DeleteFile sFile, True
    MsgBox "Deleted The File Successfully", vbInformation, "Done!"
Else

    'If file does not exists
    MsgBox "Specified File Not Found", vbInformation, "Not Found!"
End If

End Sub
```

Comment: I don't see a file `close`

Comment: I added `ActiveWorkbook.Close`. No errors now and it deletes the temp file but it is not saving the final file

Comment: Need to look through your code to see what's going on but why set books if you're not going to use them? Edit: what Darren says too.

Comment: Can't tell which one is the final file that you want to save XD And I presume Beta is the one you want to delete? If so, use `Beta.close`? I can't tell which one is the activeworkbook at the time you call `close` XD Finally, why use `saveas` earlier then change to`getsaveasfilename` later?

Answer (score 0):

You're asking for a filename to save as with `Application.GetSaveAsFilename` but you're not putting it to use:

```
Sub test()

    Dim a As String
    a = Application.GetSaveAsFilename(FileFilter:="Excel Files, *.xls")  'Ask for a filename to save as.
    ThisWorkbook.SaveAs a 'Save the file

End Sub
```

It's the end of the day, so haven't added everything - check that the result of `a` isn't FALSE or some other unusable name.  There's also various options available under `SaveAs`.